# Using WinSCP's scripting, when syncing a remote dir to a local dir, how do I make it delete the files which have been synced from the remote side?

Tags: windows, winscp

I have a server with a dir called "user-submitted data". It contains a bunch of files. I use this WinSCP command to synchronize this directory's files to my local directory:

```
synchronize local "C:\test\user-submitted data" "/test/user-submitted data" -delete
```

The `local` mode means:

> When the first parameter is `local`, changes from remote directory are applied to local directory. When the first parameter is `remote`, changes from the local directory are applied to the remote directory. When the first parameter is `both`, both local and remote directories can be modified.

And:

> -delete   Delete obsolete files. Ignored for `both` mode.

Source: https://winscp.net/eng/docs/scriptcommand_synchronize

When I run the WinSCP script, it connects and synchronizes perfectly the files from the remote directory to the local directory, but it doesn't delete any files. Only if I actually manually delete a file on the remote side and then run the script again, it deletes the local copy as well. But it doesn't delete the copy on the remote side when it's "done" (synchronized/downloaded).

How do I make it delete the remote files when they have been synchronized/downloaded?

And if I have to do it manually, how can I tell which ones have been synchronized?

And please don't tell me to use the `both` mode, because I don't want any files from the local directory to ever be uploaded to the remote side. It's supposed to be "one-way".

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out. You use the `get` command instead of `synchronize`, with `-delete`.

Comment: Wow... Can't even accept my own answer. There I get for actually trying to help others, I guess.

Answer (score 0):

When you want to delete the source files after transfer, you are not *synchronizing* the folders. Your aim is not to have the same contents on both sides at the end. Quite on the contrary.

You want to download (not synchronize) and delete the source files.

To download and delete, use [`get -delete`](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/scriptcommand_get):

```
get -delete "/test/user-submitted data/*" "C:\test\user-submitted data\"
```

There's a dedicated article on WinSCP site that covers all this: [How do I create script that synchronizes files and deletes synchronized files from source afterward?](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/faq_delete_synchronized_files)